# How to get data from html forms

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, textbox

my html page has a number of textboxes (in div tags that show/hide) and I want the data in them to send to a text document once the submit button is clicked at the bottom.

I'm fairly new to html coding and have limited php/jquery experience so if theres an easy way to do this would be appreciated. Heres the current code:

My JS:

```
function showhide(layer_ref) {
    var element =  document.getElementById(layer_ref);
    var state = element.style.display

    if (state == 'block') { 
        state = 'none'; 
    } else { 
        state = 'block'; 
    } 
    if (document.all) { //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta) 
        eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = state"); 
    } 
    if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below 
        document.layers[layer_ref].display = state; 
    } 
    if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) { 
        hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref); 
        hza.style.display = state; 
    } 
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Date: <input type="numbers" name="date">

<p><a href="test.html#div1" onclick="showhide('div1');">Question 1</a></p>
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
    <img src="q1.jpg" alt="some_text">
    <TEXTAREA Name="q1answer" ROWS=20 COLS=100></TEXTAREA>
</div> 

<!-- same code pattern for div2 to div7 -->

<p><a href="test.html#div8" onclick="showhide('div8');">Question 8</a></p> 
<div id="div8" style="display: none;">
    <img src="q8.jpg" alt="some_text">
    <TEXTAREA Name="q8answer" ROWS=20 COLS=100></TEXTAREA>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: You'll also need to use the $_POST superglobal array

Comment: **Give this a whirl too** >>> https://www.google.com/search?q=write%20content%20to%20file%20form%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: To add to my comments which **will prove** to be useful, we do not "write code" for you, we simply try to help with an existing issue you may have with "existing code" that is giving you trouble. You will often see *"What have you tried?"*, so be ready for that. `Enjoy the adventure` and **welcome to SO**, cheers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, sorry if I wasnt clear I didn't expect anyone to write the code. I just want a point in the right direction and recommendations, what I was searching for all came up with php solutions and wanted to see if there was another way

Comment: @Jason I suggest that you follow *working* tutorials, download a bunch of forms and try them out one by one. If one doesn't work, just scrap it and try another. Once you have something that you feel comfortable to work with, build around it (add or substract to/from it).

Comment: @Jason *Word of advice*; try to stay away from the **fancy stuff** (jQuery etc.) for now, and get a feel for learning how a form works, and how files can be created, modified, integrated etc. Then, once you've gotten a fairly good grasp on it, you can *prettify* it. For example: You bought yourself a car with a real powerful engine, but it needs a paint job. It'll still get you from **"point A to point B, and FAST..."**, yet the paint job can come later *(You'll thank me for it, later)* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use php GET or POST to recive data from the HTML Form.

Here is a tutorial that could help you: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: thanks, I had looked at this tutorial but thought it involved changing my current code, will take another look at it

Comment: @Jason - Tizag.com is a good place to start, I will admit. Have a look at http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php on the same site. That will give you a good idea as to how to write to file. You just need to learn to put it all together, one step at a time. Think of it as *building blocks* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML form tag into this:

```
<form action='page.php' method='post'>
```

Add a submit button before the end of form tag

```
<input type=submit name='submit' value='submit'>
```

Change the name tag of your name input field

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

into (you cant use name as a name of the input)

```
<input type="text" name="myname">
```

And add this PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //if button is clicked do this:
    $name = $_GET['myname'];
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $answer1 = $_GET['q1answer'];
    $answer2 = $_GET['q2answer'];
    $answer3 = $_GET['q3answer'];
    $answer4 = $_GET['q4answer'];
    $answer5 = $_GET['q5answer'];
    $answer6 = $_GET['q6answer'];
    $answer7 = $_GET['q7answer'];
    $answer8 = $_GET['q8answer'];
    }
else{
    //if button is not clicked do this
    }
```

Comment: I quote: *"you cant use name as a name of the input"*. You can, it's just not good practice and does leave room for confusion.

Comment: It's good, if not better practice to use `<input type="text" name="firstname">` and `<input type="text" name="lastname">` along with **validation**. `"firstname and lastname"` can be replaced respectively with `"fname and lname"` if keystrokes are a factor.

Comment: thanks usually when I do a little bit of coding I do use firstname and lastname but this time I hadn't as its only a small page with little boxes. Cheers though, seems to be going ok, just creating a php to pull the data using tutorials.